# Forcing JPA query to return eagerly all collections / fields

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, eclipselink

I have few scenarios where the server queries objects from the database by using JPA and then sends the objects to the client over web services.
Since the client expects the full graph in such scenarios I would want to override the lazy loaded collections with eager loading and probably request for batch loading (for performance). 
Is there a way in JPA (or EclipseLink) to override the query in a generic manner (without rewriting the query) and request the full graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using eclipselink, you could use the built-in query hints. That way you do not have to rewrite your jpql, but you can define the fetch type in java.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Query_Hints#Join_Fetch

Answer (score 9):

10.1.3. Fetch Joins

JPQL queries may specify one or more join fetch declarations, which allow the query to specify which fields in the returned instances will be pre-fetched.

```
SELECT x FROM Magazine x join fetch x.articles WHERE x.title = 'JDJ'
```

The query above returns Magazine instances and guarantees that the articles field will already be fetched in the returned instances.
Multiple fields may be specified in separate join fetch declarations:

```
SELECT x FROM Magazine x join fetch x.articles join fetch x.authors WHERE x.title = 'JDJ'
```

Source  : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_join_fetch